# VS Code changing language mode automatically

Tags: editor, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I am having a weird issue with VS Code. Whenever I try to open a .env file after 1 or 2 seconds it's automatically changed the language mode .env to Shell Script. As a result, syntax highlighting fades away.

If I change the language mode manually from the bottom right corner its works temporarily. If I close the file and open it again language mode automatically changed to Shell Script.

This happens only for the .env file type. I also checked the setting.json but there is nothing related to this issue.

**OS:** Windows 10 
**VS Code:** 1.60.0

**Update:** This only happens for a particular .env file.

Answer (score 3):

You can either disable automatic language detection entirely with this setting:

`Workbench > Editor: Language Detection`

or disable it for a specific language with this setting in your `settings.json`:

```
 "[env]": {
   "workbench.editor.languageDetection": false 
}
```

Use `env` there or whatever the correct language identifier is for those file types.

Comment: I just noticed that this only happens for a particular .env file.